# How do I get rid of these compiler warnings about wrong paths

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Forms and when I build for IOS I am getting a number of compiler warnings as follows

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll' was loaded from a different path than the provided path (provided path: /Users/mdouhan/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/NWMPosNG.iOS/6f3758cb3abe7365aa5a800ca6fe026c/bin/iPhone/Debug/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll, actual path: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll).  NWMPosNG.iOS
```

No matter what I google I cant find any solution to this and I am a bit aggro about compiler warnings as they clutter up and might hide real issues.

The app works as expected though.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/54705/xamarin-ios-project-dont-build-with-vs2017-update.html may helpful.

Comment: it says that was fixed in VS 15.2.2 but I am running VS 15.5.7 so seems to be a different issue no?

Comment: It is `mscorlib` dll ,different from `Encoding`, I just let you know the workaround mentioned in it.

Comment: OK I tried it and the workaround doesn't work mentioned in Comment 24 of that thread

Comment: Just bumped into these warnings for the first time. They still haven't been solved apparently!

Comment: Still an issue today!