# Why does adding the Moq NuGet package generate a MT0109 warning

Tags: xamarin, nuget, moq, .net-standard

I've started working on a vanilla Xamarin.Forms project, and I get the below warning when trying to build the iOS project, straight after adding Moq to the Forms project.

> MTOUCH : warning MT0109: The assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll' was loaded from a different path than the provided path (provided path: /Users/{me}/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.tracesource/4.3.0/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll, actual path: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.8.0.0/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll).

There are no warnings reported when adding the NuGet package itself, only when building the iOS project. In fact, there were two warnings when building but I managed to fix one.

I've tried with various versions of Moq (4.7.x, 4.8.x, 4.9.x, 4.10.x). Same issue.

I've Googled extensively but it hasn't been much help. I came across the following threads which provided some insight but didn't actually help solve the issue:

[How do I get rid of these compiler warnings about wrong paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980337/how-do-i-get-rid-of-these-compiler-warnings-about-wrong-paths)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/121551/xamarin-ios-build-assembly-path-mismatch.html

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481

**Questions**: How can I resolve this warning? Is this an issue with Moq that needs a bug repro submitted?

My environment:

- VS for Mac 2019 V8.0.4 (build 0)
- Xamarin.Forms project uses
  Xamarin.Forms 3.6.0.x, Xamarin.Essentials 1.0.1, Moq (causing the
  warning), and the target framework is .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Curious. When you say you add moq, you mean to a test project or your actual forms project? Moq is meant for testing.

Comment: I'm adding it to the actual forms project. It's not just for testing, it's primarily for mocking. I'm using it to mock dependencies for rapid prototyping.

Comment: Just to make sure it wasn't stuff I've done since creating a vanilla solution, I created a blank Xamarin.Forms solution and built the iOS project. All good. Then I added Moq to the Forms project and tried building again. Voila; warning.

Comment: ok noted. as a warning, does it stop you from building?

Comment: No it builds fine, there are no errors.